# Enterprise Architect 15.1 could not recognize C++ template

Tags: c++, enterprise-architect

I am importing C++ source files with templates inside. Enterprise Architect asks me to add them as language macros.

```
template<A::B>
void function()
{}
template<A::B a1, A::B a2, A::B... a3>
void function()
{
  implementation... 
}
```

> error: unexpected symbol: >

The problem is what do I add here as a language macro to make it work?

Comment: It sounds like you probably need to open a support ticket with https://sparxsystems.com/

Comment: What's `A::B`?  Can you include it?

Comment: Anything with :: EA will not accept as macros

Comment: @StephenNewell A is just a namespace and B is an enum.

Comment: I have also tried A(), but still don't work.

Comment: Which EA version?

Comment: @qwerty_so 15.1 ultimate

Comment: Btw: EA does not look into the source. It only reads the header files.

Comment: It automatically looks into source file if it's with the same name

Comment: The code above exists in header file, contain type traits

Comment: I'm not really using EA for code engineering (and especially not for Cxx languages). However, I'd guess you should do as @paulsm4 suggests. Maybe you can cross-post on Sparx' forum. Seems like `:` in macro names is not accepted by EA.

Comment: I have contacted Sparx, wondering when I will get a reply, I asked around EA has to add features to handle with these kind of templates

Comment: @qwerty_so which tool do u use, is it good, I may try it

Comment: It's EA 13.5 xD Don't hold your breath regarding feature requests. May take years if you see it all all (had been better some 15 years ago).

Comment: That's right :) , it's a nightmare